# What is the easiest way to write a two dimensional array to a file?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

What is the easiest way to write a two dimensional array to a file in C#?

All the questions I read so far are for string arrays but I need to write data.
I am converting an old C project and it was easy in C:

```
FILE *file;
unsigned char site[32][10];
```

Initialise the array and open the file for read/write then ( the file is always open in the project):

To write the data:

```
if (fseek (file, offset, SEEK_SET))
  return (0);
return (fwrite (&site, sizeof (site), 1, file));
```

To read the data:

```
if (fseek (file, offset, SEEK_SET))
  return (0);
return (fread (&site, sizeof (site), 1, fsite));
```

The file does not have to be open all the time so I tried:

```
byte [,] = new byte[32,10] = { some data here };
File.WriteAllBytes(fileDescr, site);
```

However it does not work with 2 dimensional arrays.

Comment: Do you need to retain the same file format as the one produced by the C program?

Comment: if the answers here are specifically for binary and your question is about binary then perhaps that should be in your title

Answer (score 5):

**References:**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
```

**Methods:**

```
public static void Serialize(object t, string path)
{
    using(Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, t);
    }
}
//Could explicitly return 2d array, 
//or be casted from an object to be more dynamic
public static object Deserialize(string path) 
{
    using(Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

**In use**

```
//Saving
byte[,] TestArray = new int[1000,1000];
//...Fill array
Serialize(TestArray, "Test.osl");

//Loading
byte[,] TestArray = (byte[,])Deserialize("Test.osl");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found this method extremely slow for large arrays (e.g. digital images).

Comment: Yeah, it appears that the binaryserializer does have performance issues with large, multidimensional arrays, but this can be currated by converting the array to a single dimensional or jagged array or by using some unsafe code like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059813/performance-issue-when-serializing-multi-dimensional-arrays-using-binaryformatte

Comment: Yes. It is possible to use pointer on multidimensional array to go through it in one-dimensional fashion (simply incrementing the pointer) while copying the data to some byte[] buffer and flushing it to disk. This is much faster then BinaryFormatter. Pointers also allow easy casting of primitive types to byte (see BitConverter implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter`.

```
public void Serialize(String path, byte[,] myArray)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, myArray);
    }
}
```

To read the file use the BinaryFormatter's `Deserialize` method.

```
public byte[,] Deserialize(String path)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[,] myArray = (byte[,])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: One question though if I use the kernel32 option will it be supported on windows8 or beyond?

Comment: Windows 8, yes; beyond that I would assume yes because Microsoft doesn't like to break backward compatibility.
I would seriously consider @MatthewWatson's version though as it's compatible with any files you've already created in the old application -- no need to read and rewrite them.

Answer (score 1):

If you must retain backwards compatibility with the old 'C' program's file format, it might be easiest to use the Windows API to write the data. (If not, you should use a `BinaryFormatter` as mentioned in previous answers).

But if you *do* want to use the Windows API, here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var site = new byte[32,10];

            using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\TEST\\TEST.BIN", FileMode.Create))
            {
                FastWrite(fs, site, 0, 32*10);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

        private static extern bool WriteFile
        (
            IntPtr hFile,
            IntPtr lpBuffer,
            uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );

        public static void FastWrite<T>(FileStream fs, T[,] array, int offset, int count) where T : struct
        {
            int sizeOfT = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (T));
            GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                uint bytesWritten;
                uint bytesToWrite = (uint) (count*sizeOfT);

                if (!WriteFile(
                    fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                    new IntPtr(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + (offset*sizeOfT)),
                    bytesToWrite,
                    out bytesWritten,
                    IntPtr.Zero
                )){
                    throw new IOException("Unable to write file.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                Debug.Assert(bytesWritten == bytesToWrite);
            }

            finally
            {
                gcHandle.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys. Im glad I asked here I was swamped with .NET solutions and none of them were the solutions suggested here. I more than one place where I have to do this and at least one of them has to be backwards compatible, and the rest don't so I will try all suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // For I/O
    using System.IO;  

    // Output Stream Writer variable
    StreamWriter yourOSW;  

    // Open the file
    yourOSW = new StreamWriter(fileName); 

    // To declare array
    byte[,] yourArray = new byte[numRows, numColumns];  

    // Data value
    byte num = 0;  

    // To fill array (example)
    for(byte i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for(byte j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
        {
            yourArray[i,j] = num;
            num++;
        }
    }

    // To write array to file
    for(byte i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for(byte j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
        {
            yourOSW.WriteLine(yourArray[i,j]);
        }
    }
```